# How do I prove that compact-open topology is metrizable?

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-compact topological space and $(Y,d)$ be a metric space.

Let $\{K_n\}$ be a sequence of compact subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$.

Define $\rho_n(f,g):=\sup \{d(f(z),g(z)): z\in K_n\}$ and $\rho(f,g)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^n \frac{\rho_n(f,g)}{1+\rho_n(f,g)}$ for all $f,g\in C(X,Y)$.

Then, it can be directly checked that $\rho$ is a metric on $C(X,Y)$.

**Assuming $K_n\subset int(K_{n+1})$ for all $n$**, it can be easily shown that $\rho$ induces the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$. However, this conditions seems too strong.

In Conway's functions of one complex variable text, it's written there that if $X$ is Baire in addition, then it can be still shown that $\rho$ induces the compact-open topology. However, I don't underatand why. How is it so? Is there any reference for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this does induce the compact-open topology as stated.

Let $X = \{1,1/2, 1/3, \dots, 0\}$ with its usual Euclidean metric (so $X$ is a compact metric space).  Let $K_0 = \{0\}$ and $K_n = \{1/n\}$, so that $K_n$ is compact and $X = \bigcup_n K_n$.  Let $Y = \{0,1\}$ with the obvious metric.  Now the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$ should simply be the topology of uniform convergence.

Now $$\rho(f,g) = \frac{1}{2} \left( |f(0) - g(0)| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |f(1/n) - g(1/n)|\right)$$
where the $1/2$ comes from the fact that $\rho_n/(1+\rho_n)$ is either 0 or 1/2.

Let $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x = 1/n$ and 0 otherwise.  Let $f = 0$.  Then $\rho(f_n, f) = 2^{-(n+1)} \to 0$ but $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems the condition $K_n\subset int(K_{n+1})$ is vital to prove that $\rho$ metrizes the compact-open topology.

Comment: @Rubertos: What may be true is that if $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and Baire, then there *exists* a sequence $K_n$ with this property.  I know it is true if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff and second countable.

Comment: I'm interested in both cases. Would you please tell me a reference? I have googled it, but I could not find anything.

Comment: @Rubertos: I don't know about the Baire case.  If $X$ is LCH and $\sigma$-compact (we don't actually need second countable) then it's a standard exercise.  Cover $X$ with compact sets $C_1, C_2, \dots$.  Let $K_0 = \emptyset$ and construct $K_n$ recursively.  Given $K_n$, by local compactness we can cover $K_n \cup C_n$ by finitely many open sets $U_1, \dots, U_m$ whose closures are compact.  Let $K_{n+1}$ be the union of their closures.

Answer (score 5):

Some more remarks: also note that you can embed $(Y,d)$ at zero price into a Banach space by the Fréchet-Kuratowski isometric embedding, so w.l.o.g. you can assume $Y$ itself is  a Banach space. The compact–open topology makes $C(X,Y)$ a LCTVS, with the family of seminorms $ \{  \|\cdot\|_{\infty,K}  \}   $ for all $K\Subset X$. It is metrizable iff it is first-countable iff $X$ is [hemicompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicompact_space), that is the family of its compact subsets has countable cofinality.